# Replace value of variable in JS file using Regex in php

Tags: javascript, php, regex, svelte, rollupjs

I want to change the value of a variable in js file using php, what i tried so far is to get the file contents and try to find a robust regex formula to change the value of the variable:

here is the contents of the js file, keeping in mind that the value can be anything between `=` and `;`

```
// blah blah blah

const filename = ""; // it can be filename = ''; or filename = null; or filename = undefined; and so on

// blah blah blah
```

i tried to get that exact line using this: `preg_match`

```
/(((\bconst\b)+\s*(\bfilename\b)+\s*)+\s*=)[^\n]*/is
```

then replaced the value usning this: `preg_replace`

```
/([\"\'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/is // to get what is between ""
or
/(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\;)/is // to get what is between = & ;
```

then replaced the whole line again in the file usning the first formula: `preg_replace`

```
/(((\bconst\b)+\s*(\bfilename\b)+\s*)+\s*=)[^\n]*/is
```

I'm asking is their a better approach, cause i feel this is too much work and not sure about the elegance and performance of what i did so far!

**NOTE: its a rollup config file and will get the bundle filename from the controller/method of current php method >> its a specific scenario.**

Comment: What's the purpose of this ? If you want your PHP to pass a value to the JS, that's definitely not the right way to do it.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't try to parse JavaScript with anything but a proper parser. Otherwise you'll have a hard time. To mention some of the easy to handle pitfalls:  `const not_filename = 0;`, `const not_fn = "filename = im_a_string";` and `const a = 1, filename = 'path', c = 3`;

Comment: i have a certain scenario for that and i know normally you don't wanna pass anything to a js file like that in runtime, but that's not in runtime, its a config js file and it will change one time before compiling to pass filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~^(\h*const\s+filename\s*=\s*).+~mi', '$1"NEW VALUE";', $string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vi9dPu/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of as line (due to `m` flag)
- `(\h*const\s+filename\s*=\s*)` - Group 1: zero or more horizontal whitespaces (`\h*`), `const`, one or more whitespaces (`\s+`), `filename`, `=` that is enclosed with zero or more whitespaces (`\s*=\s*`)
- `.+` - one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

The replacement contains `$1`, the replacement backreference that inserts the contents of Group 1 into the resulting string.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/DCO5F):

```php
$string = "// blah blah blah\n\nconst filename = \"\";\n\n// blah blah blah";
echo preg_replace('~^(\h*const\s+filename\s*=\s*).+~mi', '$1"NEW VALUE";', $string);
```

Output:

```
// blah blah blah

const filename = "NEW VALUE";

// blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if I've understood what you want to say correctly or not, but here I've tried to answer your question.

So, you want to change the value stored in `const filename = "";` using php.

Here is how your javascript file looks:

```
// blah blah blah

const filename = ""; 

// blah blah blah
```

Now, we have to get the value stored in **const filename**. So, our php should look something like this:

```
$newFilename = 'this_will_replace_the_value_in_const_filename';
$replace = get_file_contents('path_to_the_js_file');

$replaced = preg_replace('/\s*const\s+filename\s*=\s*\"(.*)\"\s*\;/', "const filename = '$newFilename';", $replace)
```

Now the new string that has the manipulated value of **const filename** is stored in `$replaced`. You can print it using echo, as under:

```
//php
echo $replaced;
```

**Output:**

```
// blah blah blah

const filename = 'this_will_replace_the_value_in_const_filename'; 

// blah blah blah
```

Comment: Adding a new answer as a comment on a different answer is easily lost. I would recommend adding comments on the answer you have additional questions to. Or adding a additional section at the bottom of your original question with follow up questions so it is clear what the history is.